# I want to update T1 using T3 column and by using three table relationships

Tags: oracle

```
UPDATE TABLE1 T1 SET T1.CENTERNAME=
(SELECT AC.CENTERNAME 
FROM TABLE2 T2 INNER JOIN TABLET3 AN ON T2.CENTERID = T3.LOCATIONID 
INNER JOIN TABLE1 T1 ON T3.LOG_ID = T1.LOGID W
HERE TRUNC(T1.ROW_DATE)='25-MAR-2014');
```

This gives the error '**ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row**'.

Comment: The error message is really clear, your inner select statement returns more than one row. You need to fix that. We don't know what your data structure is like.

Comment: Do you really want to be joining to a new version of `table1` in the subquesery, or is that supposed to be correlated to the outer one?

Answer (score 0):

The error message

```
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
```

means, er, the sub-query returns more than row.  That is, this part of your statement ...

```
(SELECT AC.CENTERNAME 
FROM TABLE2 T2 INNER JOIN TABLET3 AN ON T2.CENTERID = T3.LOCATIONID 
INNER JOIN TABLE1 T1 ON T3.LOG_ID = T1.LOGID 
WHERE TRUNC(T1.ROW_DATE)='25-MAR-2014')
```

returns more than row.  The error occurs because the SET part of the UPDATE depends on the equality operator - `SET T1.CENTERNAME=` - so it can take only be one value.

Without more details about your data structure it is hard to be certain but I suspect what you really want is something like this

```
UPDATE TABLE1 T1 
SET T1.CENTERNAME= (SELECT T2.CENTERNAME 
                    FROM TABLE2 T2 
                            INNER JOIN TABLE3 T3
                        ON T2.CENTERID = T3.LOCATIONID 
                    WHERE T3.LOG_ID = T1.LOGID )
WHERE TRUNC(T1.ROW_DATE)='25-MAR-2014'
/
```

(I've tidied up your redaction to make the aliases consistent.)